# I want to use while loop when user input is not in the list

Tags: python

```
List_of_name={
"ahmed":("student","21"),
"mohmeed":("employee","24")
}
name=input("write the name  :")
Print(list_of_name[name])
```

I need use while loop that when a user puts a name that is not in the list the  program asks him again

Like this

```
While name != List_of_name:
    name=input("write the name  :")
```

Any solve ?

Comment: What was wrong with what you wrote for "Like this"?  What do you think `name != List_of_name` means?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something simple like

```
while name not in list_of_names.keys():
    name = input("write the name  :")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done this way:

```
List_of_name = {"ahmed":("student","21"), "mohmeed":("employee","24")}

while True:
    name = input("write the name :")
    if name in List_of_name.keys():
        print(List_of_name[name])
        break
```